# What is the difference between not (!) and not equal (!=) is C++?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

And where do i use them? I am a beginner, so try to understand me please.
I googled around for some info but i really coudln't find anything.
I saw some code snippets with parts like `if(!a)`, but how is that gonna work? Isn't it like `if(a is not a)`? Will that if cycle do the instructions in his parenthesis?

Comment: is [google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) not working?

Answer (score 4):

If `a` is "false" then `!a` is `true`. If `a` is "true" then `!a` is `false`

When you use `!=` you have a direct comparison against some other value. For example `a != 1` is only `true` if the variable `a` is not equal to `1`.

If anything, `!a` could be equivalent to `a == 0`.

---

Of course the above does not mention anything about operator overloading. If there are overloaded operators `!` or `!=` for `a`, then the behavior depends on the overloaded operator implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `!` is used on one item, while `!=` is used between two.

1. `!` of an expression is usually used only when that expression is a Boolean, like:

   ```
   bool ok = true;
   ...
   if (!ok) ReportError();
   ```

   You can use `!` on integers - but then that is special:

   - `!0` becomes `1`
   - `! anything else` becomes `0`.
2. `!=` is used to compare two similar things:

   ```
   if (i!=5) ReportError();
   if (response!='Y') Quit();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_typehttp://) data type is?

Great!

Now, if(a) is short for if(a == True). Therefore, if(!a) naturally means if(a != True).

Comment: No i don't. I am abeginner i said that.

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator means NOT.
So if `x` is a number: `if(x != 3)` and `if(!(x == 3))` are equivalent.

So basically, if `b` is any Boolean expression/value itself (something that can be either true or false, it can be an inequality or any other condition), using `if(b == true)` and `if(b)` is equivalent; and so is using `if(b == false)` and `if(!b)` because `b` is a Boolean just like any other condition.

To go back to my previous example, saying `if(x != 3)` is like saying `if((x != 3) == true)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, I suggest you to please read the C Bible "The C Programming Language - Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie".

It is a good hand book for every C/C++ programmer by the creators of the language themselves.